# GSON JsonObject getAsString() UTF-8 issue

Tags: java, gson, json

I have a json value "test":"d'exécuter" and when i print it with gson's `getAsString()` method it displays d\u0027exâ”œâŒ?cuter or d'ex??cuter. How do i get the actual value "d'exécuter"?

```
String envServices = System.getenv("SERVICES");
JsonObject services = new JsonParser().parse(envServices).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray arr = (JsonArray) services.get("dev.dev"); //$NON-NLS-1$
if (arr.size() > 0) {
    services = arr.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject credentials = services.get("credentials").getAsJsonObject();
    String val = new String((credentials.get("test").getAsString()).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String val1 = new String((credentials.get("test").getAsString()));
}
```

The JSON value is as follows

```
SERVICES={"dev.dev": [{ "name": "WDS",  "credentials": { "url": "http://test.com", "username": null,"test":"d'exécuter", "password": null } } ] }
```

Comment: Show us how you produce `credentials`.

Comment: Updated the question. The json file is actually a .env file

Comment: This is an encoding issue of your environment. Instead of reading the JSON from an environment variable, put it in a text file with UTF-8 encoding and read it with UTF-8.

Comment: Is there a way i can change the encoding of the .env file to UTF-8?

Comment: What do you mean _.env file_? The `getenv` is getting from your system environment. I don't know how encoding works there.